named semaphore wont work as assumed in synchronization between process
given writer & reader code as follows, the program just wont work as it assumed to be:
expect behavior:  after we launch the writer, then after typically 2s, we startup reader from another terminal, due to semaphore protection, the reader should block waiting on the semaphore to be 1, and then print out the derived msg.
however, the outcome is quite the opposite.
firstly, we launch the writer process in a terminal, the output is as:
shared mem address: 0x10cc68000 [0..511]
backing file: /dev/shm/shMemEx
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

wait for namely 2s, then run the reader process, while almost immediately, the reader print out the semaphore 'protected' data:
mac@mbp cpp % ./r
hello worldThis is the way the world ends...

writer.c:
// compilation on macos: gcc -o w writer.c -lpthread
// compilation on linux: gcc -o w writer.c -lrt -lpthread
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "shmem.h"

int main(){
    int fd = shm_open(BackingFile, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, AccessPerms);  // r/w + create
    if(fd < 0){
        report_and_exit("can't open shared mem segment");
    }
    ftruncate(fd, ByteSize);                       // adjust the backing file size

    caddr_t memptr = mmap(
        NULL,                                      // let system pick shared mem seg pos
        ByteSize,                                  // bytes
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,                    // access protections
        MAP_SHARED,                                // shared mem visible to other proc
        fd,                                        // fd
        0                                          // offset: start at 0
    );
    if((caddr_t) -1 == memptr){                    // mmap creation check
        report_and_exit("can't get segment...");
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "shared mem address: %p [0..%d]\n", memptr, ByteSize - 1);
    fprintf(stderr, "backing file: /dev/shm%s\n", BackingFile );

    sem_t* semptr = sem_open(                      // create semaphore to lock the shared mem
        SemaphoreName,                             // name
        O_CREAT,                                   // op = create
        AccessPerms,                               // protection perms
        0                                          // init value
    );
    if(semptr == (void*) -1){                      // semaphore creation check
        report_and_exit("sem_open");
    }

    // fprintf(stderr, "semaphore address: %p\n", semptr);

    strcpy(memptr, MemContents);                   // write to mem (copy ascii bytes to shared mem seg)

    int num = 8;                                   // wait 8s -> reader should not access
    while(num > 0){
        printf("%d\n", num);
        num--;m
        sleep(1);d
    }

    if(sem_post(semptr) < 0){                      // incr semaphore after writing finish, let reader access
        report_and_exit("sem_post");
    }

    sleep(6);                                      // for reader to be scheduled
                                                   // cleanups
    munmap(memptr, ByteSize);                      // unmap the storage
    close(fd);
    sem_close(semptr);
    shm_unlink(BackingFile);                       // unlink from the backing file
    return 0;
}

reader.c
// compilation on macos: gcc -o r reader.c -lpthread
// compilation on linux: gcc -o r reader.c -lrt -lpthread
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>       
#include <fcntl.h>          
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "shmem.h"

int main(){
    int fd = shm_open(BackingFile, O_RDWR, AccessPerms);  // r/w without create
    if(fd < 0){
        report_and_exit("can't get file descriptor...");
    }

    caddr_t memptr = mmap(                                // ptr to mem
        NULL,                                             // let system pick mem seg pos 
        ByteSize,                                         // bytes of shared mem
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,                           // access protections
        MAP_SHARED,                                       // shared mem is visible to other proc
        fd,                                               // fd
        0                                                 // offset: start at 0
    );
    if((caddr_t) -1 == memptr){                           // 
        report_and_exit("can't access segment...");
    } 

    sem_t* semptr = sem_open(                             // semaphore as mutex
        SemaphoreName,                                    // name
        O_CREAT,                                          // create semaphore if not existed
        AccessPerms,                                      // protection perms
        0                                                 // init val
    );
    if(semptr == (void*) -1){                             // err return if semaphore create failed (non-block)
        report_and_exit("sem_open");
    }

    if(!sem_wait(semptr)){                                // wait until semaphore != 0, then start reading
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<strlen(MemContents); i++){
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, memptr+i, 1);            // one byte at a time
        }
        sem_post(semptr);                                 // incr semaphore by 1
    }

    munmap(memptr, ByteSize);                             // cleanup
    close(fd);
    sem_close(semptr);
    unlink(BackingFile);                                  // if omitted, file will persist after program exit
    return 0;
}

shmem.h
#define ByteSize 512
#define BackingFile "/shMemEx"
#define AccessPerms 0644
#define SemaphoreName "mysemaphore"
#define MemContents "This is the way the world ends...\n"

void report_and_exit(const char* msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(-1);
}

the code source: https://opensource.com/sites/default/files/gated-content/inter-process_communication_in_linux.pdf

Your semaphore is not being cleaned up properly. You need to add a sem_unlink() to the writer to "really" destroy the semaphore.
If you don't all of the sem_opens() will just get whatever value the semaphore last had (and the reader does a sem_post after printing the results so it's not 0)
You can confirm by trying to open with O_CREAT | O_EXCL in the writer which will tell you the semaphore already exists.

This is paste cannot solve the above in the front way, but provide a feasible approach to it.
here provide another way to test the semaphore between threads, rather than between processes, which seems worked as assumed.
/* compilation: gcc -o t test.c -lpthread -lrt */
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int shared_var;

void* writer(void* arg){
    bool* flag = (bool*) arg;
    sem_t* sem = sem_open(                      // create semaphore to lock the shared mem
        "testsema",                             // name
        O_CREAT,                                   // op = create
        0644,                               // protection perms
        1                                          // init value
    );
    if(sem == (void*) -1){                      // semaphore creation check
        printf("sem_open");
        return 0;
    }
    if(*flag){
        sem_wait(sem);
    }

    shared_var = 10;                               // critical section
    printf("writer set var as %d\n", shared_var);
    int num = 8;                                   // prevent reader get in 
    while(num > 0){
        printf("%d\n", num);
        num--;
        sleep(1);
    }

    if(*flag){
        sem_post(sem);
        sem_close(sem);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* reader(void* arg){
    bool* flag = (bool*) arg;
    sem_t* sem = sem_open(                      // create semaphore to lock the shared mem
        "testsema",                             // name
        O_CREAT,                                   // op = create
        0644,                               // protection perms
        1                                          // init value
    );
    if(sem == (void*) -1){                      // semaphore creation check
        printf("sem_open");
        return 0;
    }
    if(*flag){
        sem_wait(sem);
    }

    printf("reader get var as %d\n", shared_var);  // critical section

    if(*flag){
        sem_post(sem);
        sem_close(sem);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {    
    bool enable = true;
    sem_unlink("testsema");   # unlink some weired existed dirt
    pthread_t wt0, rt0, rt1, rt2;

    pthread_create(&rt0, NULL, reader, (void*) &enable);
    pthread_create(&wt0, NULL, writer, (void*) &enable);
    pthread_create(&rt1, NULL, reader, (void*) &enable);
    pthread_create(&rt2, NULL, reader, (void*) &enable);

    pthread_join(rt0, NULL);
    pthread_join(rt1, NULL);
    pthread_join(rt2, NULL);
    pthread_join(wt0, NULL);

    sem_unlink("testsema");   # must unlink to avoid pollution
    return 0;
}

if set the enable as true inside main function, the output typically becomes:
reader get var as 0
writer set var as 10
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
reader get var as 10
reader get var as 10

during the writer count down on critical section, nothing is broken by reader.
while let's simply set the enable=false in the main, check it again:
reader get var as 0
reader get var as 10
writer set var as 10
8
reader get var as 10
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

we can easily observe the intruder reader broken in.
thread level shared mem exert some ingredient here. More detailed invest needed.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
